# Monohybrid Cross

Tags: genetics

There are two types of pea plants according to Mendel:
1)Tall(TT or Tt)
2)Dwarf(tt)
But I have a doubt! Is there a heterogeneous dwarf pea plant(tT)? When there can exist a heterogeneous tall pea plant, there must exist a heterogeneous dwarf pea plant also! This doubt is troubling me very much! Please clear my doubt!

Answer (score 2):

Why `there must exist a heterogeneous dwarf pea plant also`. I don't understand why you think it must be the case.

Under this simple genetic model, there is no environmental variance and `T` is dominant over `t` (`t` is therefore recessive) and therefore the heterozygotes `Tt` have the same phenotype than the homozygote `TT`. There is no `Tt` individuals that have the same phenotype as `tt`.

If `t` was dominant, then `Tt` individuals would have the same phenotype as `tt` individuals. If `T` and `t` were perfectly additive, then `Tt` individuals would have a phenotype half way between the `TT` and the `tt` phenotypes (`Tt` would be of average height).

Please note, that very few real life cases are that easy. There is often interaction between many loci and there is often (if not always) environmental influence on the phenotype.